How to pass arguments to a windows syscall in NASM assembly?
I am learning how to implement direct system calls using nasm assembly and c code, I have created a funcs.asm that contains
section .text
global NtOpenProcess

NtOpenProcess:
    mov rax, 26h
    syscall
    ret


and in main.c I have
extern NTSTATUS __stdcall NtOpenProcess();

int main()
{
    HANDLE proc = NULL;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES obj_attr = {sizeof obj_attr, 0, NULL, 0};
    CLIENT_ID cid;
    cid.UniqueProcess = (HANDLE)316;
    cid.UniqueThread = 0; 

    NTSTATUS res = NtOpenProcess(proc, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, &obj_attr, &cid);
}

I am sure that the arguments are located in the following registers

rcx -> proc
rdx -> contains the PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS (1FFFFF)
r8  -> obj_attr
r9  -> cid

but if I compile and run the above code I would get a segfault,
My guess is that I should probably rearrange the arguments on the registers, but I am clueless on what the right order is

It might be that you passed wrong arguments to wrong registers. This might help you.

mov rcx, 1FFFFF and mov r8, proc are right. The other two, I do not know.

This answer may guide you.

__stdcall is hopefully meaningless in 64-bit code...  The only Windows x64 calling conventions are fastcall (normal x64 like you're using) and vectorcall (same but with __m128 in an XMM reg.)

RCX is definitely not where the arg goes for syscall.  The syscall instruction itself overwrites RCX (with user-space's RIP, so it can avoid writing memory.)  Linux system calls use R10 for system calls instead of RCX, so a syscall wrapper function like this would use mov r10, rcx.  Windows might make the same choice; that faintly rings a bell in my memory.

Note that direct syscalls are not supported on Windows.  While that may appear to work initially, system call arguments and numbers do change from Windows version to version.  Do not do direct syscalls on Windows.  Call into kernel32.dll instead.

An answer on System Calls in Windows & Native API? confirms that Windows does indeed use R10, e.g. that mov r10, rcx appears in ntdll!NtCreateFile

It is true that windows system calls SSN change but this rarely happens for well known and used functions such as NtOpenProcess it has 0x26 across all window 10/11 builds.

An answer on Assembly Syscalls in 64-bit Windows shows a table of which register for which arg for the Windows syscall ABI.  That's what you're missing, so marked it as a duplicate.  (Unless there's something else wrong in your code; I didn't check.)
